# How to remove a list that contains certain element from a list

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = [['yes','no'],['riding','0']['riding',1],['yes','no'],['yes','no'],['riding',2]]
```

needs to remove all the list that contains riding 
so it would give me

```
a = [['yes','no'],['yes','no'],['yes','no']]
```

I have a big list , and the list that contains riding are in no predictable sequence
how do i remove them ?
thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple for loop:

```
for l in a.copy():
    if "riding" in l:
        a.remove(l)
```

Comment: If you try this on the OP's example you'll end up with `[['yes', 'no'], ['riding', 1], ['yes', 'no'], ['yes', 'no']]` because you're removing elements from a list you're iterating over, which confuses the iteration.  You'd need to iterate over a copy instead.